# While loop does not break even after the condition is satisfied, but same code starts working if I use a "printf" in the while loop

Tags: c, embedded, atmel, atmelstudio

I will first explain the situation :

1. This is a menu driven program in which the option selected keep on executing until other option is fed
2. The option is fed to the microcontroller through USB port and an ISR calls the function that handles the parsing of the input command
3. The program runs just fine as long as the option that enters the infinite while loop is entered
4. After it enters infinite loop it can not break from it even if the command to stop the program is entered.
5. The Program DOES ENTER the ISR even when it is executing the while loop as has been checked by using a printf in the ISR.
6. When command to stop the program is encountered in ISR it sets the flag which is checked by the while loop.
7. NOW for the weird part. The same code starts working if I insert a printf("%u",command) in the while loop.

The sudo code is as follows :

```
ISR_USB()
{
    char command=read_from_buffer();
    printf("Entered ISR and command = %c",command); // Prints on serial port and confirms the program entered ISR 
    if(command==STOP_DEMO)
        FLAG_TO_BREAK_WHILE=true;
    printf("%u",FLAG_TO_BREAK_WHILE); // Confirms correct value of flag is set
    command_parser(command);
 }

 command_parser(command)
{
    if(command=='1')
         printf("HELLO WORLD");
    else if(command=='2')
    {
        printf("While started");
        while(!FLAG_TO_BREAK_WHILE); // Gets stuck here 
        /*
         starts working if the above while is replaced by :
         while(!FLAG_TO_BREAK_WHILE)
         {
          printf("%u",FLAG_TO_BREAK_WHILE);
          }
        */
    }
    else if (command=='3')
        printf("stop command executed");
}
```

please help me understand the situation here and this behavior.

NOTE: THE PARSER IS IN ANOTHER FILE AND THE VARIABLES ARE EXTERNED.

Comment: is the flag volatile?  If not it might need to be.

Comment: Embedded systems 101 : https://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/beginner-s-corner/4023801/Introduction-to-the-Volatile-Keyword

Comment: It has been figured out this is a volatile thing.  But in general if adding a printf or some such similar call results in success where there was otherwise failure one of two things happened, 1) a delay the printf caused a delay so you had a race condition 2) the printf obviously changes the code so there was a change in the compiler output  2a) this could be a compiler bug you have exposed or 2b) as we see here a programmer bug that you have exposed. or a very distant 2c) a chip/processor bug...In all cases your first thought should be to examine the assembly output of the compiler

Comment: a delay/race condition or a bug in your code being the two prime candidates when a printf fixes something.

Comment: @old_timer is race conditions something I should be concerned about when working with a single core embedded system with out an os? If yes then how does it take place in such a system? And great debugging tip going for assembly. A lot of bugs that are not caught by directly looking at code are rectified there

Comment: number of cores doesnt matter, without an os is more likely to have an issue.  the race is not just with other cores but with anything inside or outside the system.  maybe during development you had printfs, compiled for debug, etc and didnt realize you needed to put a delay in before poking some register in a peripheral or reading a gpio pin, etc...build for release, remove the printf, now you have issues.  race conditions are between any two entities, processor and internal peripheral, external peripheral, etc...

Comment: I think SO needs a canonical duplicate for "how to fix my horribly coded ISR".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is happening is that `while(!FLAG)` is being optimized to

```
if(!FLAG)
{
    while(true)
    {
         //do stuff
    }
}
```

To fix this define the flag as volatile and the compiler will be forced to read the flag from memory every time it is accessed by your code.

Comment: I understand the use of volatile in this code but why does adding printf make the code work  ? is it because printf forces the compiler to check the value or something ? or is it that that it is optimized such only if the while is empty ?

Comment: Because the optimizer chose to not perform this optimization.  Maybe your compiler did not know if printf made any changes to global memory so it was forced to reevaluate the global flag.  Maybe the expensive printf call made the optimizer think that this relatively minor optimization was not worth it.  Either way, both of these things are most likely implementation defined, and there is probably some implementation where the version with printf would loop forever.

Comment: @user19961 examine the disassembly to understand what happened in this case.